# why google signin JavaScript function execute on every pageload

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am signing in with the gmail using google API on my website and after signed in I am storing the Id, Username, Email and Image url in Database using Ajax call and in response showing the modal. All going well but if user closes the modal without signed out and reload the page my onSignin function executes every time the page is refreshed/reloaded.

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div>
    </div>

    function onSignIn(googleUser) {
    var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
    var profile_Id = profile.getId();
    var profile_Name = profile.getName();
    var profile_Email = profile.getEmail();
    var profile_Image = profile.getImageUrl();

    //ajax call for saving profile information satrt
    $.ajax({  
        type: 'POST',  
        url: '../action.php', 
        data: {Id:profile_Id, Name:profile_Name, Email:profile_Email, Image:profile_Image},
        success: function(response) {                
            console.log("Response: " + response);
            $('#username').html("Hi "+profile_Name+"!");
            document.getElementById("sign-in").style.visibility = "visible";
            $('#RatingModal').modal('show');
        }
    });
    sessionStorage.setItem("Id", profile_Id);
    $("#LoginModal").modal('hide');
    }
```

Comment: You need to find where the function is called first. This is only the function definition.

Comment: <div class="form-group">
            <div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div>
 </div>
this is where the function is called and this is only single definition of the function

Comment: This is the HTML, not the JS. Try to find "g-signin2" and "onsuccess" in your project

Comment: I don't have any function with "g-signin2" or "onsuccess". but as far my understanding on successful sign in of the user the above onSignIn function executes.

Comment: inside onSignIn function, do console.trace() it will tells you which function call it. There's always a start